# How do I use RPC to get operation through hash

Tags: transactions, rpc, operation, hash

I want to get a transaction by its hash. For example, there is this api provided by tzscan: `https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operation/{op_hash}`. I want to know how to do the same using the node RPC, but I am not able to find the answer from the official documents.